# How can we make vscode & cmake detect GTest on VScode on windows 10?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake, visual-studio-code

I was developing c++ project on linux before.
The project requires google test.

Now, I'm trying to migrate it to visual studio.
Since the project does not have solution ".sln", I need to create it via *cmake -G "Visual Studio ...."* (I run this command using VSCode).
But, since my project requires google test, namely CMakeLists.txt includes

```
find_package(GTest REQUIRED)
```

the GTest is supposed to be installed.

Unfortunately, the VSCode cannot find Gtest, which says

```
Could NOT find GTest (missing: GTEST_LIBRARY GTEST_INCLUDE_DIR GTEST_MAIN_LIBRARY)
```

For this reason, I could not migrate the environment to Visual Studio.

How can we make GTest be detected?